# Join product hierarchy to customer table

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

This is for an MSQL2012 instance

I currently have an issue joining a client data table to a hierarcy, my aim is to produce an output table that shows what they do not own on the first level.

I'm having issues with the client ID, as when you compare the tables the outputs overlap and give exceptions for all client ID's, and not for each client ID

Could anyone help me in generating the syntax for this type of issue?

```
product_data
     Level 1, Level 1 Name, Level 2, Level 2 Name
       1         Fruit         2        Apple
       1         Fruit         3        Banana
       1         Fruit         4        Orange
       5         Vegetable     6        Potato
       5         Vegetable     7        Celery

client data
   Client ID, Level 1, Level 1 Name, Level 2, Level 2 Name
       1       1          Fruit         2        Apple
       1       1          Fruit         3        Banana
       2       5          Vegetable     5        Potato
       2       1          Fruit         4        Orange

Desired Output
   Client ID, Level 1, Level 1 Name, Level 2, Level 2 Name
       1          1       Fruit         4        Orange
       2          1       Fruit         2        Apple
       2          1       Fruit         3        Banana
       2          5       Vegetable     7        Celery
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: MSQL Management Studio 2012

Comment: your table design is very unconventional .so you need to explain those two tables product and client data along with column name.you need to explain the output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```sql
SELECT  cln1.ClientID, cln1.Level1, cln1.Level1Name, prd.Level2, prd.Level2Name
FROM    product_data prd
INNER JOIN client_data cln1
    ON prd.Level1 = cln1.Level1
LEFT JOIN client_data cln2
    ON cln1.ClientId = cln2.ClientId
    AND prd.Level1  = cln2.Level1
    AND prd.Level2 = cln2.Level2
WHERE   cln2.Level2 IS NULL
```

Comment: Could you by any chance be able to help me with the methodology behind this please?
As i'd need to implement it accross a few more levels, otherwise, its giving me some promosing results, thanks!

Comment: first inner join is to get the data that intersects (exists in both tables) at level 1. This is fairly straightforward. Now that we have set which have records of products and clients where clients have the level 1 items our next step is to check the level 2 items.

However here the output is not what the client has at level 2 but what the client does not have. So how do we get what the client doesn't have by joining two sets? That's basically where the LEFT JOIN comes in. It joins the table in the left join with the set above irrespective of whether the record exists or not.

Comment: If any record or a joining column doesn't exist in the table in the left join SQL SERVER will simply put value null to that column. Hence the check for Level2 IS NULL in the WHERE condition. 

I know this explanation might be bit confusing but here is an example if you wanna try out and see.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left

Comment: Works perfect, had to make a few changes, but if there was a few more levels to the hierarchy the code would change by adding in for example prd.Level3 = cln2.Level3 and changing the where statement to level 3, correct?

Comment: Correct. Depending on the situation you might need to union two such queries if required.